# Подсчет кол. найденых слов в одном столбце по выражению like в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, like

Есть такая таблица в БД:

```
id    title
 1    one two
 2    one three
 3    one
 4    three
 5    one two three
```

и есть запрос вида:

```
SELECT id where title like '%one%' or title like '%three%
```

Он вернет все строки в которых будут значения `'one' 'three'`. По сути он вернет подряд строки 1,2,3,4,5. Мне необходимо, чтобы он первыми вернул строки, в которых максимальное количество совпадений, т.е. должен вернуть 2,5,1,3,5. 
Я думаю, что нужно по каждому найденому слову лайком добавлять какой-нибудь переменной score 1 очко, потом сортировать по этой переменной. Но как это сделать, не знаю.

Может есть какoe либо решение?

Сделать при помощи PHP не могу, т.к. данные с БД получаю порциями по 25 записей, а для того, чтобы обработать при помощи PHP необходимо получить весь набор данных.

Comment: Выглядит как задача для полнотекстового поиска.

Comment: По факту это система поиска по релевантности которую я дорабатываю , не могу прикинуть как релевантность в sql реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table_test
WHERE title like '%one%' or title like '%three%'
ORDER BY sum(CASE WHEN title REGEXP '(one|three)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

PS этот код не тестировался...

Answer (score 0):

В принципе нашел интересное решение такого вида

`SELECT name
FROM table_test
WHERE name LIKE '%строка_поиска%'
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN name LIKE 'строка_поиска' THEN 0
WHEN name LIKE 'строка_поиска %' THEN 1
WHEN name LIKE 'строка_поиска%' THEN 2
WHEN name LIKE '% строка_поиска%' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END`

Доработал под свой вариант начало сортировать по совпадениям.